# ASIC BRS SOAP API service Binding Bug

Tags: python, django, soap

I was pulling my hair building ASIC(Australia) Business Registration (BRS) App for a client. ASIC SOAP API in UAT has an a bug in a service binding within a soap response. It returns an incorrect URL.

Answer (score 0):

the following code fixes this problem:

```
def your_wsdl(DocumentHeader, DocumentBody):

    """Call ASIC using the SOAP API listin the BRS document
    :param DocumentHeader: dictonary with the fields as specifed in BRS documentation 
    :param DocumentBody: dictonary with the fields as specifed in BRS documentation
    """


wsdl = Config.objects.get(code="ASIC_API").value + str('?WSDL')
wsdl_session = Session()
wsdl_session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth(Config.objects.get(code="ASIC_API_ID").value, Config.objects.get(code="ASIC_API_PASS").value)
transport = Transport(session=wsdl_session)
client = Client(wsdl, transport=transport)

##get_service2 fixes the incorrect binding response in BRS UAT
service = get_service2(client=client)


soap_response={}
with client.settings(raw_response=True, xsd_ignore_sequence_order=False):
    try:
        soap_response= service.externalInitiat
    except Exception as e:
        soap_response = { 'status_code': 500 }
```

def get_service2(client):

```
    """Fix for the incorrect Service Binding
    :param client: soap client object
    """

service_binding = client.service._binding.name
service_address = Config.objects.get(code="ASIC_API_url").value
return client.create_service(service_binding, service_address)
```